# Replacing a dataframe's index value with dict's values?

Tags: python, pandas, function, csv, dictionary

so i'm trying to define a function capable of reading relevant dataframes and replacing the index values for the values of a dictionary from a .csv file.
I have something like this as my dataframe:

```
            ARR
ID               
1           3
2           3
3           3
4           3
5           3
6           3
7           4
8           4
9           4
10          5
```

Next i have a .csv file with my ID's and their correspondent names(students).
The function i created was something like this:

```
def naming(x):
    with open(path) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = list(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','))
        y = {}
        for i in csv_reader:
            y.setdefault(i[0],i[1])
        for j in x.index:
            if j == y.keys():
                x = x.replace([x.index], y.values())
```

I created a y dictionary with keys = ID's and values = names. However i seem to have a problem with the logic behind replacing the index values of an x dataframe and i can't seem to make it work.
Whenever i summon my function naming(x) and apply it to my dataframe. The values aren't replaced.
Any help? What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: if you could show the contents of the csv file and the result you hope to get, that would help to understand what you are trying to achieve. That being said, one issue right off the bat is that your function doesn't return anything, so it's probably not giving you what you expect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution, assuming you have names for all ID's.

```
my_dict = {1:'jim', 2:'mike', 3:'sally', 4:'pete', 
           5:'helen',6:'max',7:'joe',8:'fred',9:'jane',10:'raul'}

d = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'ARR': [3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

my_list=[]

for id_s in df['ID'].values:
    my_list.append(my_dict[id_s])
    
df['name']=my_list
df = df.set_index('name')  
df = df.drop('ID', 1) #remove this line if you want to keep the ID column
```

I would also recommend reading your csv file with pandas read_csv. Make sure to replace your own filepath within the brackets.

```
df = pd.read_csv('./folder/files/filepath')
```